# In Nginx is there any metric or a way to know if we have reached max_size limit

Tags: nginx

Below is the proxy_cache_path definition. In Nginx is there any metric or a way to know if we have reached max_size limit

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/folder1 levels=2:2:2 keys_zone=folder1:125m inactive=4m max_size=200g;
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/folder2 levels=2:2:2 keys_zone=folder2:1m inactive=7d max_size=1g;
```